# Bash script output not being written to log file

Tags: bash, unix, logging

I've got a pentaho job which prints out java logger stuff to console if you run it manually.  There should be hundreds of lines being logged.  I have it scheduled as a cron job, and while the job seems to run fine, the logging stuff isn't being placed in the log file.

I have a start and end `echo` statement, and those are being writted to the log file.

Batch file:

```
echo "Starting daily cron run"
export KETTLE_HOME=/opt/appdata/app/
$PENTAHO_HOME/kitchen.sh -rep="APP_UNIX" -job=run_all
echo "Daily cron run completed"
```

The cron job:

```
5 3 * * * /home/e_app_s/load_all_etl_unix.sh > schedule.log
```

What schedule.log looks like:

```
Starting daily cron run
Daily cron run completed
```

Anyone see a problem here?  Thanks.

Comment: Where is `$PENTAHO_HOME` defined?

Comment: Almost invariably, when running a job manually works and executing it from cron does not, the cause is a difference between your environment and cron's environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I defined $PENTAHO_HOME explicitely instead of using the variable.  It worked.